# Overriding abstract method of Java class in Scala with bounded inheritence

Tags: java, scala, generics, inheritance

I have an abstract class in a library I wanted to implement in Scala, which has abstract copy method with bounded inheritance as follows:

```
// Java code
public abstract class Base {
      public abstract <T extends Base> T copy();
}
```

When I create a class in Java it works fine, i.e.

```
public class FromBase extends Base {
     @Override
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public FromBase copy();
}
```

But if I try to do it in Scala the below gives `method 'copy' overrides nothing`:

```
class FromBase extends Base {
    override def copy(): FromBase = new FromBase()
}
```

And the below IDE-suggested works but requires call with type `v.copy[FromBase]()` to work:

```
class FromBase extends Base {
    override def copy[T <: Tuple](): T = (new FromBase).asInstanceOf[T] 
}
```

Since the method can be called from Java, I need a copy without generic to work, as in the Java example.

Comment: There is something strange: the base class requires the copy method to return some subtype of the base class itself, while the last snippet introduces a tuple class. Is that just a typo?

Comment: Yes, that is a typo; I was just simplifying an existing problem, which occurs working with Tuple classes for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of `Base.copy` says it can return *whatever subtype of `Base` it's asked for*. It's entirely valid to write

```
Base base = new FromBase;
AnotherBaseSubclass base2 = base.copy();
// same as AnotherBaseSubclass base2 = base.<AnotherBaseSubclass>copy();
```

This obviously can't work if `FromBase.copy` actual return type is `FromBase`.
So the "warning" you are suppressing should be an error and Scala doesn't allow it.

It's likely that you actually need `T` on `Base`, not `copy`. If you fix this:

```
// Java code
public abstract class Base<T extends Base> {
      public abstract T copy();
}

// Scala
class FromBase extends Base[FromBase] {
    override def copy() = new FromBase
}
```

it will compile and not require any casts or suppressed warnings.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Just to clarify, if the method is defined as above there is no valid way to overload it in Scala, am I right? The issue in this case is that the Base method is a part of a library and I cannot really change the way how it's defined.

Comment: There is also no actual valid way to implement it in Java. The closest to valid way in Scala is the IDE-suggested one you give in the question. It doesn't require specifying the type parameter if the expected type is known, just as in Java: `val base2: FromBase = v.copy()`.

Comment: But unless you simplified too much, this design strongly suggests the library authors didn't understand generics and it shouldn't be used (at least without wrapping it in a more reasonable API).